# problem using django's User authentication model. Uncomprehensible error

Tags: django, authentication, model, modelform

I want to register users.
So I made a:

```
class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User #(from django.auth.contrib.User)
```

now i display that form in a template for the users to fill it and to submit it.
When i do form.is_valid(), i  get this validation error: `Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.`

Does anyone know what can cause this?
i've included the `ModelForm`, the view that processes the registration form and the template that displays the registration form.
Thank you for your time and kind concern.

```
MY MODEL FORM
class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User

THE VIEW THAT HANDLES THE REGISTRATION
def register(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): # HERE I GET A VALIDATION ERROR
            new_user=User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                          password=form.cleaned_data['password'],
                                          email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
                                          )
            new_user.is_active=True
            new_user.first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            new_user.last_name=form.cleaned_data['lastname']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('confirm_registered'),args=[form.cleaned_data['username']])
        else:
            return render(request,'login/register.html',{'form':form})
    else:
        raise ValueError()
```

THE REGISTRATION TEMPLATE

```
{% extends "store/index2.html" %}

{% block canvas %}
<h3>Registration</h3>


{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="/retailstore/login/register.html">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.first_name.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.first_name }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.last_name.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.last_name }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.email.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.email }}</td>
</tr>

</table>

<input type="submit" value="register" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Rule 1.  Indent correctly.  If you indent your code (and not other junk) it looks like Python code.  Rule 2.  Spell correctly.  "I" refers to yourself.  Please fix your spelling and your indentation.  It's quite hard to figure out what "enter code here" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is not validating, but your template is set to always show the same error message about username and password not matching:

```
{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}
```

The reason it is not validating is probably because you are only using some of the fields from the User object, and a `ModelForm` expects *all* of the non-editable fields.  In the Form's Meta, set

```
 fields = 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'
```

to tell it to only require those fields.

Also note that passwords are not stored in the database as plain text, so creating a user with a password like that will not work.   You need to use `user.set_password(form_password)`.

Answer (score 0):

As Dave points out, you always show the same message no matter what the validation error. You should do this:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {{ form.errors }}
{% endif %}
```